# Can anyone help me to set lights on my scene?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am done my project with modeling and texturing.In this case this is Marantz Vintage amplifer, but problem is that because I don't have idea how I can set light on scene to look like commercial photo and realistic like one of my first render.[image]

[image]

I have a model and black world background,two spot lights and that's it.
Can anyone have idea how I can set lights on that scene.

Here is complete scene file, feel free to give any idea.
https://www.sendspace.com/file/q3vezo

Comment: I'd suggest creating a studio like lighting setup, similar to what is used for product photos. For an easier solution you could use a studio HDRI and a backdrop.